# Does $\int x^ndx = \frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n + 1} + c$ for all real $n$?

Tags: integration

I know it's established where $n$ is integer except for $-1$.
$$\int x^ndx = \frac{1}{n + 1}x^{n + 1} + c$$
But, I'm not sure if it's established where $n$ is real number.
Is it established where n is real number except for $-1$?
If so, would you introduce the proof please?

Comment: Of course, when $n$ is irrational, we need to have $x^n$ defined at least.  So we could restrict this to $x>0$.  Or we could use complex values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have $y = x^\pi$ take logs and differentiate:

$$\ln y = \ln x^\pi = \pi \ln x$$

$$\frac{1}{y}y' = \pi \frac{1}{x}.$$

Multiply both sides by $y$ and then remember what $y$ was:

$$y' = \pi \frac{1}{x} y = \pi \frac{1}{x} x^\pi = \pi x^{\pi -1}.$$

So that's how the differentiation rule works for any real number.  And so your anti-derivative rule works for any real number except $n = -1.$

Comment: Then, Is that true for negative real number n? Isn't the differential coefficient complex number for negative real number n?

Comment: @David I don't quite follow, but the problem would be if $x$ were negative.   The sign of $n$ doesn't matter.

Comment: I apologize. I made a typo. My question was "Is that true for negative real number x?".

Comment: @David For negative $x$, you have to deal with complex log's.  So you have to choose a branch of log and make sure you don't integrate across the branch cut.

Comment: This also works for non-real $n$ if you're careful about the branch cuts.

Answer (score 2):

Are you happy with the corresponding rule for differentiation? If so then this follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of calculus.
Let $n \ne 1$ be an arbitrary real number and $f(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$.

FTC says that if $f$ is $C^1$ (which it is since f is a poly) then $$\int_a^x f'(t)dt = f(x)-f(a)$$ which exactly says $$\int_a^x t^ndt = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}a^{n+1}$$ or in indefinite integral notation
$$\int x^ndx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + c$$

To prove the derivative of $x^n$ for $n$ real, use Newton's generalised binomial theorem and the limit definition of the derivative.

Comment: Reading the problem statement, I think he might want to know why $f'(x)=x^n$ as well, especially for real $n$ (not just integer is what I'm saying)